# How many passwords with 8 characters have :

Tags: combinatorics, multinomial-coefficients

How many passwords with $8$ characters ( $26$ lowercase $26$ uppercase and $10$ digits ) have :

a) exactly $3$ lowercase characters $3$ uppercase characters and $2$ digits

b) all characters are different

for $b)$ the answer should simply be $\binom{62}{8}$ because we need different characters.

for $a$) there should be some multinomial distribution right there.
We can have $\frac{8!}{3!3!2!}$ ways to get the $ 3-3-2 $ distribution but we need to choose from the total number of lowercase/uppercase characters and digits. Do we simply multiply by the binomial coefficient? How to approach this?

Comment: Yes, for part a, the multinomial coefficient you have picks the positions in the password which have each type of character. Now you have to assign actual characters to those positions. Essentially the same advice holds for part b, though picking the characters first and then ordering them is a bit roundabout.

Comment: Is repetition of characters permitted?

Comment: The repetition of characters is permitted, indeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a)

For an ordered sequence of $3$ lowercase letters there are $26^3$ possibilities.

For an ordered sequence of $3$ uppercase letters there are $26^3$ possibilities.

For an ordered sequence of $2$ digits there are $10^2$ possibilities.

Maintaining the order of these sequences we must select $3$ of $8$ spots for the lowercase letters, $3$ of $8$ spots for the uppercase letters and $2$ of $8$ spots for the digits, and this gives $\frac{8!}{3!3!2!}$ possibilities.

We conclude that there are: $$\frac{8!}{3!3!2!}\times 26^3\times26^3\times10^2=\frac{8!}{3!3!2!}\times 26^6\times10^2$$such passwords.

b)

There are $26+26+10=62$ possibilities for the first character, $61$ for the second character, et cetera.

So there are $$62\times61\times\cdots\times55=\frac{62!}{54!}$$such passwords.

Comment: Brilliant! thank you.

Answer (score 1):

a) First choose the positions of the digits, then assign the digits, then choose the positions of the uppercase letters, and assign the letters. The total number of combinations thus equals:

$${8 \choose 2} 10^2 {6 \choose 3} 26^6$$

b) First choose the characters, then assign them to their position in the sequence:

$${62 \choose 8} 8!$$